How can I get both of these formulas into one cell?
I want to have both the results 'Follow Up Count' and 'Conversions' to be in the same cell.


I've tried various ways of using & and many other ways but I can't seem to get it right.
What am I doing wrong? Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Use the & operator, like this:
="Follow up count: " & countif(I3:I, "Follow-up") & " — Conversions: " & countif(F3:F, "Order Placed")

See concat() a.k.a. &.
